# How do I handle slow readers in Netty?

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty

In my application I have can have thousands of readers each fetching documents.

I need to have the ability to buffer slow readers so that I can move on to handle other readers so that I can get maximum usage of the disk and CPU.

How is this usually done? I could of course use the TCP send buffer but I think these would fill up fast.

Another strategy is to keep a separate buffer which is just a queue of ChannelBuffers which would be bounded.

I assume that if ANY of these buffers fill that I should just fail that client since it can't read fast enough?

Comment: to date I just keep a queue of the pending message but this seems nasty.  Further, I have one disk thread and one network thread and ideally I would have a way to pass message across them quickly.  I could use ConcurrentLinkedQueue of course but it seems to just be a duplication of the tcp send buffer.  So I should just use that.  If I need it bigger I can just re-size the buffers in the app.

Comment: It's best to make an attempt at some code first, then post the code if you have additional problems or want to find ways of doing it better.

Comment: I agree but the problem I'm having isn't writing the code but the design of the code.  :)

Comment: Then write the pseudo code :)

Answer (score 1):

You *are* using the TCP send buffer. That's the thing that fills up first. Then you start getting zero length writes. At that point you should do two things:

1. Stop producing output for that connection.
2. Register the channel for OP_WRITE, and when it fires retry the last write. If that succeeds, deregister OP_WRITE and continue normally.

In my opinion you should also stop *reading* from that channel while it's in state 2. If it's still producing requests and isn't consuming the responses, that's its problem, not yours. There's no reason for you to keep producing responses that it isn't reading, and no reason to waste your memory keeping them around until it deigns to read them.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have the ability to buffer slow readers so that I can move on to handle other readers so that I can get maximum usage of the disk and CPU.

Netty takes care of this for you really.  Since you are single threaded you can't wait around for the client to read anything otherwise you'll lock up your single thread and nothing happens.  So you can just write to your ChannelBuffer, it doesn't block, and after you return it to netty it will send it later.  Hence freeing up your thread to service another client while that other buffer is being sent or not sent to a client.  So if a reader is slow you just end up with a ChannelBuffer that is filled up, but not being read.

Now if something is truly not read by a client you do have a ChannelBuffer (or many) just taking up room, but you can use this to be notified if something has taken too long and clean it up:

http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/timeout/ReadTimeoutHandler.html

There is also this too:

http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.html